# How to keep left & right margins equal on separate pages

Tags: margins

This must be a really common problem but I haven't find notes that address it in a satisfying way.

Why does tex create an automatic indention when texts are going cross into the next page?

[image]

Screen shot of the code
[image]

Comment: Screen shots of code are difficult to read and impossible to copy. There is never a good reason to include them that I can think of. `\bf` is 20+ years deprecated, by the way, and ought not be used in LaTeX.  `\\ ` should not be used except in special environments such as tabulars. You do not show enough code to answer your question. Probably you have `twoside` or you do not have `oneside` as a class option but all anybody can really do is guess. Please post a Minimum Working Example with code we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce if my guess does not solve the problem.

Comment: This is not a good behavior in general, what if the last paragraph in the previous page has a very final line full of characters? We won't notice a new paragraph break!

Comment: @cfr Hey thanks I added oneside to \documentclass and it worked

Comment: @AboAmmar Yes, we will ;).